# What replaces FacesContextUtils in Spring 3?

Tags: spring, jsf

We just upgraded from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0.7.  The class:

```
org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils
```

doesn't appear exist in 3.0.7.  We are trying to call:

```
FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBeansOfType(type);
```

Is there a replacement in Spring 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class also exists in Spring 3.0.7, maybe you missed a jar or downloaded a different release?

You can use the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also get the jar from the [spring repo](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.web&version=3.0.7.RELEASE).

If this doesn't help you may update your question with the stacktrace of the error msg.

Comment: You are right.  I was having Maven problems, I think it fooled me.